# Npm audit report says 'found 1 low severity vulnerability' karma > expand-braces > braces

Tags: angular, npm, npm-audit

Npm audit report says 'found 1 low severity vulnerability'. 1 vulnerability requires manual review.

```
  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service
  Package         braces
  Patched in      >=2.3.1
  Dependency of   karma [dev]
  Path            karma > expand-braces > braces
  More info       https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/786
```

However, manually upgrading braces(braces": "^2.3.2") did not resolve the issue.
Any suggestions?

Following are the content of my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.23",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mat-video": "^2.6.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`? Or at least the `dependencies` section of it?

Comment: I chose to ignore it because it is low severity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that updating it yourself doesn't correct the issue is that it doesn't update the dependency of a package you are using. In this case it's karma, which is dependent upon a version of braces that has this vulnerability.

Comment: Do you mean there is no way I can use "karma": "^4.0.0" until unless this vulnerability is resolved by karma package itself?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. This is not uncommon when using different packages built on some shared core dependency and a vulnerability is discovered. Some authors update more quickly than others. This one is pretty low in concern, so I wouldn't stop development but if your org requires a clean audit for CI/deployment or anything, then it may be a problem.